# How I can Add variables to PHP.ini using chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, opsworks

I am using redis into my project using chef. We are creating server automation, so everything is done using chef recipe's only. I have installed php-redis using chef. Now I need to add two variables into my php.ini defining my session path.

Since we are doing every configuration using chef, I would like to know how can I add variables into php.ini using chef. Searched on web a lot and everybody recommended to use your own php.ini file instead. Which one is the best solution and any guidance on the same will be highly appreciated. I am very new to chef.

Comment: Environment variables aren't usually wet in `php.ini`. You'd typically do it at the server or webserver level.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how you have structured deploying `php.ini` in the first place.

However, assuming you are using the most current [php cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/php), this has support for adding directives to the default `php.ini`

This is done by creating a Hash of attribute `:key => value` pairs as a node attribute and the underlying template will render these at the end of the file.

Here's an example of how to override the Hash with a few variables, where this might be placed inside another cookbook's attribute file that depends on the `php` cookbook:

```
override['php']['directives'] = {
  :memory_limit => '128M',
  :post_max_size => '16M',
  :upload_max_filesize => '12M'
}
```

This will be used in the [php.ini template](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/php/blob/287e8e07e0860ef3ad4bae7d7a433f2b70c43731/templates/default/php.ini.erb#L1898-L1900) to render these attributes at the end of the file.

You can override attributes at a variety of layers - I recommend reading the [About Attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) to get a deeper understanding on how to use attributes effectively.

Comment: @Ankur Was there any follow-up question about this answer? Did it work out for you?